# extract propertie in array of objects to string

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have this array of objects and i need to export to string , all the db values.

```
   [
          ...

          {
            "db": "DT_INI_PROC",
            "prv_value": "",
            "nxt_value": "",
            "diagnostic": "",
            "datatype": "date"
          },
          {
            "db": "DSP_PROC",
            "prv_value": "",
            "nxt_value": "",
            "diagnostic": ""
          },
...
          {
            "db": "DESCRICAO",
            "prv_value": "",
            "nxt_value": "",
            "diagnostic": ""
          },
          ....
        ]
```

and i need a string with all "db" separated by comma as:

```
"...DT_INI_PROC,DSP_PROC,...,DESCRICAO..."
```

Comment: And what is the problem? Where is your code?

Comment: It's a job for `.reduce()`

Answer (score 2):

You can use `Array#map` and `Array#join` methods.

- `Array#map` to get only the `db` keys values.
- `Array#join` to change the returned array into a string.

```js
var arr = [{
      "db": "DT_INI_PROC",
      "prv_value": "",
      "nxt_value": "",
      "diagnostic": "",
      "datatype": "date"
    },
    {
      "db": "DSP_PROC",
      "prv_value": "",
      "nxt_value": "",
      "diagnostic": ""
    },
    {
      "db": "DESCRICAO",
      "prv_value": "",
      "nxt_value": "",
      "diagnostic": ""
    }
  ],
  res = arr.map(v => v.db).join(',');

console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 2):

Just reducing should be sufficient;

```js
 var data = [{
            "db": "DT_INI_PROC",
            "prv_value": "",
            "nxt_value": "",
            "diagnostic": "",
            "datatype": "date"
          },
          {
            "db": "DSP_PROC",
            "prv_value": "",
            "nxt_value": "",
            "diagnostic": ""
          },
          {
            "db": "DESCRICAO",
            "prv_value": "",
            "nxt_value": "",
            "diagnostic": ""
          }],
  result = data.reduce((p,c) => (p.db += "," + c.db,p)).db;
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```js
var data=     [
          

          {
            "db": "DT_INI_PROC",
            "prv_value": "",
            "nxt_value": "",
            "diagnostic": "",
            "datatype": "date"
          },
          {
            "db": "DSP_PROC",
            "prv_value": "",
            "nxt_value": "",
            "diagnostic": ""
          },

          {
            "db": "DESCRICAO",
            "prv_value": "",
            "nxt_value": "",
            "diagnostic": ""
          }
          
        ];
        
        var res = data.map(function(v,i) {return v.db;});
        console.log(res.join(','));
```